# AngularJS Validation on ng-show not working on when select2 is added

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I am using select2 of bootstrap to have a search dropdown menu but the problem is the validation is not working. Previously it is working without the select2 but now its not working and the message is shown always.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addEmployee.formAdd.pos.$invalid && !addEmployee.formAdd.pos.$pristine }">
    <label>Position</label>
    <select name="pos" id="pos" ng-model="addEmployee.employee.employee_positionID" class="form-control select2" required>
        <option ng-repeat="option in addEmployee.position" value="{{option.position_id}}">{{option.position_name}}</option>
    </select>
    <p ng-show="addEmployee.formAdd.pos.$invalid && addEmployee.formAdd.pos.$dirty  && addEmployee.formAdd.pos.$touched  && addEmployee.formAdd.pos.$error.required" class="help-block">Position is required.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think, your <select> doen't have empty value. That is why required error doesn't seem.

Comment: @Natiq what do you mean with the empty value? please elaborate

Comment: Add this line before ng-repeat : <option value=''>Please select</option>

Comment: @Natiq still not working

Comment: full code please with form ,this half code will not help and what is select2 ?

Comment: what is addEmployee.formAdd. convention.  If formAdd is the form name, then is it not the outer dom element.  This is a **[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbT0NKs0MryrQEcPU6qE?p=preview)**, which shows that this works.  But since you check for $dirty and $touched along with $error and $required, you won't see the error when the page loads (when $dirty and $touched are false).  But if you select another element and then the first placeholder, you see the error.

Comment: the error is shown onload, the error must hide when not yet touched or if field is empty

Comment: @Mahesh formAdd is the form name

Answer (score 0):

you can still validate from controller after trying to save the form using:

```
if ($scope[formName].$invalid) {
       e.preventDefault();
       angular.forEach($scope[formName].$error, function (field) {
               angular.forEach(field, function(errorField){
                       errorField.$setTouched();
               });
       });
/*add some notification to user here*/

       return;
}
```